# How can I search tags on StackOverflow Careers?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, jobs

I am attempting to search jobs by tag on `StackOverflow Careers`. On SO, this is done using square brackets, but that is simply doing a keyword search, and I still get results that don't have the tag I am looking for.

For example, when I search for the keyword "android", I get this:

> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=android&location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles

which is the same as when I search for the keyword "[android]":

> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=%5Bandroid%5D&location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles

Is there a format I can use to search jobs by tag? If not, I believe this would be a nice feature (seems intuitive for the Stack Exchange invite-only job site).

Comment: Yeah, the [`/jobs/tag/android` route](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/android) shows the same results, which include things that only have Android as a keyword and not a tag. My guess is that there's currently no way/it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Should this be tagged as a bug, or is that way it *should* be?

Comment: Admittedly I'm not sure. If this behaviour *is* intentional, it's not exactly intuitive, so it may be part bug, part feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a format you can use to search jobs by tag.

The reasons a bit more interesting.  First, tags are not a required field in a job listing.  So over 20% of jobs do not include them.  Second, we're still working with employers to be smarter about tagging.  We continue to see some odd results when a non-technical HR manager fills in the tags.

We *could* implement the [ ] format for searching, I'm just not convinced that it would be helpful yet.  We'll add this to our schedule because the SO power users may be able to derive some benefit out of it, but it won't be as helpful until we make job tags a stronger signal.

Comment: This answer is old, but at this time I strongly disagree that it wouldn't be helpful to searchers.