# Tag search not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Looks like tag search doesn't work at all. clicking on any tag brings up the same view of 1545 jobs.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I search tags in Careers 2.0?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168976/how-can-i-search-tags-in-careers-2-0)

Comment: There seem to be more tagged jobs than there are jobs: [This](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs) returns only 1312 jobs.

Comment: The short answer is that this appears to be expected because contrary to the URL, it's not *actually* intended to show things just tagged with the given tag (it's effectively just a keyword search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed! And fixed, please try it again.

Comment: yep, working now! http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/ruby